# Адаптивный блок Adsense не подстраивается

Tags: html, css, адаптивность, google-adsense

Почему-то адаптивный блок Adsense не всегда адекватно подстраивается по ширине экрана. Бывает так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е., нормально.

А бывает так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

viewreport есть.

Comment: Только нативная так. Обычное адаптивное объявление нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос непростой, там генерируется iframe и внутри него сиди еще один iframe. Управлять их внутренними стилями простыми способами нереально, ну а внешними...
Есть только одна идея:
1) обернуть рекламный блок в див с overflow: hidden;, который режет всё торчащее из него и не даст иного распирать страницу широкими баннерами, как сейчас.
2) на ресайз страницы - генерировать событие обновления этого блока.

Как-то так.

Comment: Это проблема гугла? Допустим, на жесткие ограничения он не реагирует. - http://prntscr.com/hdqwux
Может для телефонов подгружать изначально другой блок? Так как такой бред есть только на нативной рекламе гугла, на обычной адаптивной все ок.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас стили подгружаются после показывания блока, или меняется его ширина тоже после подгрузки через JS. Можете вынести стили блока-контейнера и его родителей, влияющих на ширину, в inline-стиль в `<head>` - 99%, что проблема решится. Именно поэтому ширина и пляшет - в зависимости от того, что подгрузилось раньше (ведь AdSense грузится в async режиме). Ну или просто добавьте нужные стили в inline style родительских элементов (хотя первый способ предпочтительнее).

PS: про inline стили - на самом деле Google рекомендует именно так и делать для верхней части страницы. Гуглите "critical path (fold) css", eg: http://prgssr.ru/development/razbiraemsya-s-kritichnym-css.html